# About variables

Tags: php, variables, global

So if I have a variable in a php file I just made , if I put it in the same folder as other php files and include it into one of them , I can use any variable from that file right?
Sorry if it's a bit of noobish

Comment: It depends where the variable is in the PHP file, and where you're including that file.

Comment: One advice: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) (click the link and read the page!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically yea. Running the [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) is equivalent to pasting the code.

Specifically, from the PHP manual:

> When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs. **Any variables available at that line in the calling file will be available within the called file, from that point forward**. However, all functions and classes defined in the included file have the global scope.

In general the PHP manuals are pretty much self explained. You will find there most answers for basic questions as this one.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

[From the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined. For
>   the most part all PHP variables only have a single scope. This single
>   scope spans included and required files as well. For example:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
include 'b.inc';
?>
```

> Here the $a variable will be available within the included b.inc script.

Note that this also works in the other direction:

```
<?php
  /* a.inc */
  $a = 1;
?>

<?php
  /* b.php */
  include 'a.inc';
  echo $a;
?>
```